# A problem about connected spaces

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bourbaki exercise on connected sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/bourbaki-exercise-on-connected-sets)

Let $X \subset M$ be both connected spaces. If $C$ is a connected component of $M-X$, then $M-C$ is connected.

My try: Let´s suppose that $A,B$ form a separation of $M-C$  i.e $
M - C = A \cup B
$ and also holds that $
\overline A  \cap B = A \cap \overline B  = \varnothing 
$
. Clearly  $
M = C \cup A \cup B
$ is a disjoint union. And since $C$ it´s a connected component, $C$ it's closed. If I prove that $
A \cup B
$ it's closed, then I'm ready. How can I prove that no limit points of $A$ or of $B$, lies in $C$? Please help me!

And clearly I can suppose that X lies in A without loss of generality. But also considering that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Unless I'm completely mistaken, this is exactly part b) of the linked question.

Comment: Yes you are right! . But there is no answer of that question!