# Let $Y⊂X$; let $X$ and $Y$ be connected, If $C$ is a component of $X-Y$, then $X-C$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This question is similar to exercises in munkres 23-#12 : "Let $Y\subset X$; let $X$ and $Y$ be connected. show that if $A$ and $B$ form a separation of $X-Y$, then $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected"

So I tried to similarly.

Let $A,B$ is separation of $X-C$. Since $Y$ is connected, $Y\subset A$ or $Y \subset B$. Suppose $Y \subset A$.

No limit point of $A$ can be $B$, and no limit point of $C$ and be $B$ so that $A \cup C$ is closed, and $B$ is open.

And I tried to show that no limit point of $B$ can be $A$ and $C$, but I didn't.

That is, I want to show that $B$ is open in $X$.
How does it work?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/363789/4280) to a slightly different question which contains the argument you need.